# Restarts to install menu with usb in. Restarts to black screen and flashing underscore with usb out

Tags: boot, usb

So i'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 and I can install Ubuntu, but when it restarts with the USB in, it acts like Ubuntu wasn't installed. It goes to the install, try, ect menu. When I take out the USB, after my pc says press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to go to boot options, it turns to a black screen with a flashing underscore. I've tried 2 different USB installers now.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is GRUB, which is the bootloader (what allows Ubuntu on your hard drive to boot), was installed to your USB INSTEAD of your hard disk.

### How to Fix:

Turn off your computer and plug your USB back in.

Turn on your computer.

Now, when a login prompt shows up, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to enter a TTY Session.

Now, it'll show a prompt like this:

```
ubuntu login: _
```

Enter your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then, enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**NOTE**: The username and password are the ones you supplied during the installation process. Also, when you type your password, no characters will appear (be echoed back). This is normal behavior.

Now, once you login successfully, you should be at a prompt like this:

```
user@hostname:~$
```

Now, remove your USB from the computer (you can just pull it out, it's fine).

Then, enter the following command to install the bootloader. This command will ask for your password again.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Let it finish. Then once it's done, enter the following command to reboot your computer.

```
sudo reboot
```

If all goes well, your computer should reboot and boot into Ubuntu with no problems.

If this doesn't work / problems arise, please do comment!

Comment: I don't go into a login screen. I tried what you said in the trial, but it just said it couldn't find /cow and it was Ubuntu@ubuntu. When I startup with the usb in, it just goes to the usb's install.